# Filtration in the Serre SS

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I knew this at one point, and in fact it is embarassing that I have forgotten it. I am wondering what filtartion of the total space of a fibration we use  to get the Serre SS. I feel very comfortable with the Serre SS, I am just essentially looking for a one line answer. I checked have Hatcher, Mosher and Tangora and Stricklands note on Spectral Sequences.

I think it has something to do with looking at cells where the bundle is trivializable..

Comment: I don't remember, but my bet is: filter the base by skeletons, and the total space by their preimages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup. I win the bet :)

See J. M. McCleary's *User's guide to spectral sequences*, Chapter 5.

Comment: I always forget about that book...
PS have you ever looked at Browder's book about surgery?